# ¿Como puedo crear una carpeta en la memoria interna en Android?

Tags: java, android

No encuentro la forma para crear una carpeta en android. Con java es diferente que crearlo en Windows.

**¿Como puedo crear una carpeta en la memoria interna de un teléfono con java?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si quieres crear una carpeta en la memoria privada, lo haces con:

```
File nuevaCarpeta = new File(getFilesDir(), "miCarpeta");
nuevaCarpeta.mkdirs();
```

Si quieres crear una carpeta en la memoria externa, sea memoria fija o tarjeta SD, primero necesitas agregar un privilegio al manifesto:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

luego lo creas como:

```
File nuevaCarpeta = new File(getExternalStorageDirectory(), "miCarpeta");
nuevaCarpeta.mkdirs();
```

Como ves, no es tan distinto a Java.

Más informaciones encuentras en [almacenamiento de datos](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html), una parte de la documentación oficial que ya esta traducido a español.

En el enlace también se menciona que hay que discriminar entre apps de `Android 4.3-` y `Android 4.4+` Pre 4.4 no se podría acceder a tarjetas SD usando `getExternalFilesDir()` en dispositivos que tuvieron parte de la memoria fija como sistema de archivo externo, desde 4.4 existe `getExternalFilesDirs()` que devuelve un arreglo de carpetas para datos externos.

Comment: Mi problema era que no sabia donde se creaba la carpeta, para crear la carpeta adentro del teléfono a simple vista utilizar esto:                                 String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()

Comment: Eso es como ves en la respuesta para acceso a la SD, memoria interna se accede con `getFilesDir()`, como también explicado en la respuesta. En el enlace encuentras más maneras como persistir datos. :)

Comment: Jaja que raro entonces porque con getFilesDir() no me funcionaba pero cuando intente con getExternalStorageDirectory()  me funcionaba  y crea la carpeta en la memoria interna

Comment: Estas seguro? Eso no debe ser así.

Comment: Si seguro en mi propio teléfono realize la prueba y ese método para acceder en la memoria interna lo encontré en ingles que era utilizar getExternalStorageDirectory()

Comment: Ah, creo que entiendo ahora. "memoria interna" con `getFilesDir()` es almacenamiento privado para yu aplicación dentro de la memoria. `getExternalFilesDir()` o `getExternalStorageDirectory()` se refieren a memoria SD, no al ram, independiente si es memoria fija o de una tarjeta SD.Parece que fui ambiguo en como lo dije.

Answer (score 0):

```
    File ruta_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File nuevaCarpeta = new File(ruta_sd.getAbsolutePath(), "miCarpeta");
```

A mi me funciona a la perfección de esta manera, tmb puedo crear carpetas dentro de otras carpetas en la memoria externa, basta con hacer esto:

```
    nuevaCarpeta2  = new File(ruta_sd.getAbsolutePath()+"/miCarpeta", "otraCarpeta");
```